# Erro no processo de DebugResources

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

Será que alguém pode me auxiliar na resolução deste erro que está ocorrendo. Formatei minha máquina e instalei a versão do Android Studio 2.1.2. 
Como não tenho domínio da plataforma, não sei se pode ser alguma coisa de configuração da aplicação ou não. Se alguém souber algo que possa me ajudar eu agradeço!

[image: Erro]

Comment: Podes postar o código todo do `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: Claro, segue o código:

Answer (score 0):

```
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

            <activity android:name="com.arielacrippa.saudetotal.MainActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.arielacrippa.saudetotal.activitys.Cadastros" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.arielacrippa.saudetotal.activitys.Configuracoes" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.arielacrippa.saudetotal.activitys.Relatorios" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.arielacrippa.saudetotal.activitys.Usuários" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

As seguintes ***tags***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

de `uses-permission` tem que ficar fora da *tag* `application`!

**Edit**

Tente deixar assim seu `AndroidManifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.arielacrippa.saudetotal">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity
    android:name=".Cadastros" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
  <activity android:name=".Configuracoes" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
  <activity android:name=".Relatorios" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
  <activity android:name=".Usuários" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Eu fiz, conforme você sugere, mas continua com erros e quando dou um clean project as <user-permission> voltam para dentro da tag application

Comment: Este projeto é importado do Eclipse pra o Android Studio?

Comment: Não, iniciei um projeto novo no android.

Comment: @ArielaCrippa Fiz um update na resposta, tenta deixar assim teu arquivo do `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: consegui resolver!  Era um bendito acento em um classe :/ Muito obrigada pela suas dicas e atenção!